# How to Update query with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   UPDATE 
      mine
    SET
      reason = 'is this possible?',
      deleted = 1,
    WHERE id = '1'
    GROUP BY date
```

I want to update 2 rows different id but same value, is this possible?

Comment: what's the purpose of `group by date`?

Comment: No, this is not possible.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  As written, the `group by` makes no sense.  Just remove it.

Comment: Depending on what you actually mean (which isn't clear) you can update different rows by setting `WHERE id='1' OR id='2'...etc`. The `GROUP BY` looks redundant.

Comment: value of 1 and 2 are same the different is the ID i want to update the 2 rows in the same time

Comment: just set the where clause to `WHERE samevalue = 'same'` then

Answer (score 2):

You can update as many rows as you want at the same time.  For instance, to update ids 1 and 2:

```
UPDATE  mine
    SET reason = 'is this possible?',
        deleted = 1
    WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

In fact, you can leave out the `WHERE` clause entirely and update *all* rows in the table.

I'm not sure why you have `GROUP BY date`, but `date` doesn't seem relevant to the query.